# can't find JRE in the JDK

Tags: jvm, java

i install JDK in

> **C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_24**

and set the variables as follow:

> **JAVA_HOME**:  C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_24
>
> **CLASSPATH**:  .;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_24\lib;C:\Program
>   Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_24\lib\tools.jar;
>
> **PATH**:    C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_24\bin

but when i run the **java -version** command , the error

> **could not open `C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\lib\i386\jvm.cfg'**

comes up. then i move the jre folder out the jdk folder to

> C:\Program Files\Java\

and change the folder name to **jre6** (then it has the **C:\Program Files\Java\jre6** folder) , everything becomes good then .

why this is happening ? it seems to me that it is not the environment variables that are controlling the JVM's location.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it is not the path that is controlling the location of the JRE it must be the registry:

[http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.3/runtime_win32.html](https://web.archive.org/web/20110813040025/http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.3/runtime_win32.html).

Comment: yea it is using the registry . it is using a registry key called **HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\JavaSoft\Java Runtime Environment** with string JAVA_HOME set to the jre's location rather than the jdk's location which is what you do when setting environment variables.   thank you!

Answer (score 0):

On Windows 64 bit OS check also:
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\JavaSoft\Java Runtime Environment

Answer (score 0):

I set my

**JAVA_HOME**: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-14.0.2

worked fine for me.