# Unable to start Eclipse -- can't open \Java\jre6\lib\i386\jvm.cfg

Tags: eclipse, java

```
could not open C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\lib\i386\jvm.cfg
```

is the error coming when i am trying to start eclipse ide.

my `C:\Program Files` has

```
jdk1.6.0_14
jdk1.6.0_17
jre6
```

folders.

path is set to

```
PATH: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_17\bin
```

what is the problem

i have seen this link but it is not solving my problem
[can't find JRE in the JDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5204451/cant-find-jre-in-the-jdk)

Comment: i think the path is:
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_17

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I also had this problem and was having trouble finding a solution, but now I did!

If you uninstall your current running jre version and then install higher one you are good to go.

I was using jre1.6 when I had this problem but after installing 1.7 it was solved!

Answer (score 9):

I had similar problem on a Windows machine. I had moved my Java directory from inside "Program Files" (the space in the directory name was giving me trouble) over to c:\

I set all my PATH variables to the new location, restarted the machine and thought that would be enough. Nope

java -- version

> Error: could not open `C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_66\lib\i386\jvm.cfg

This solution came from the good folks over at coderanch

Start regedit (just type "regedit" into the Run program) and work your way down to HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE > SOFTWARE > JavaSoft

There you will find several different java directories

Java Development Kit

Java Plug-in

Java Runtime Environment

Java Update

Java Web Start

In each directory you'll find different directories for the different version of java (esp. Java Web Start). Open each and every one and you'll see that your old path is still listed. Double click the Name (left column) of the listing and manually type in the new path.

Open a new terminal and type in Java - version and you should be fine.

Answer (score 8):

This problem can show up if you initially install Java in the default location (C:\Program Files) and then later re-install into another location.

The default installation copies java.exe, javaw.exe and javaws.exe to C:\Windows\System32. If you are in this situation and delete these files it will likely solve your issue.

(Thanks to Jay: http://jaykhimani.blogspot.com/2012/09/error-could-not-open-cprogram.html)

Comment: glad that my blog post helped you.

Answer (score 5):

Problem: Eclipse Neon error: "C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0xx.xx\jvm.cfg"

Solution Win7 Pro: System Properties > Enviorment Variables > System Variables > Path > Edit > #make sure the current JAVA directory appears first in the path if  more than 1 JAVA directory exist.

In the path that follows, I moved "C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath" behind the current directory "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jre\bin" > save

Path
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jre\bin;C:\apache-maven-3.5.0\bin;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath

Answer (score 3):

I recently got the same problem on my Windows 7.  The issue was that two different paths were specified for Java in the path environment variable. This can be checked as follows.

On the command prompt, run the following command:

```
> where java

C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath\java.exe <br/>
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_192\bin\java.exe
```

The first one was the cause of the issue and **removed it from the path**.
Eclipse is working now without re-installation.

Note: The environment vars have been as follows always:

1. JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_192
2. JRE_HOME=C:\ProgramFiles\Java\jdk1.8.0_192\jre

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that your eclipse cant find jre.Just copy and paste your jre folder into eclipse folder and then start eclipse.Delete environment variable.

Answer (score 1):

What worked for me was to go back to the Java webpage and download the Java jre instead of the jdk, since that is what the stupid computer is now looking for.  Then open the C: Program Files>Java and make sure you see jre7 instead of jdk.

RS

Answer (score 1):

Have a simpler solution:

Check your PATH.  Most likely it is referring to incorrect java.exe.  This started happening to me when I installed OS patch.  In process of checkpoint etc, PATH got modified.  Once I corrected it (using Environment Variables...), it worked immediately.

Answer (score 1):

Try putting below line in your eclipse/STS -STS.ini file

-vm
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121(your JDK version)\bin\javaw.exe

Put it at the top of the file.
Most probably it will work.

Sometimes putting javaw.exe in eclipse folder also work (where eclipse.exe is there)

Answer (score 0):

This is an old post, but what solved my solution was editing the `eclispe.ini' file to include the  correct path to the JDK.

Building off of what Lars answered, I did reinstall Java, so that may have been the source of the issue.  Reglardless, this is the solution that worked for me.  I did not have to delete any files from C:\windows\system32, however.  I merely told eclipse to look in the new Java installation directory.

These [docs](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse.ini#Specifying_the_JVM) indicated I needed to specify the path to the VM:

```
-vm
C:\Java\jdk1.7.0_25\bin\javaw.exe
```

Answer (score 0):

This problem mainly occurs when we install new jre or jre gets updated automatically since jdk version and jre version are different and path variable i.e. JAVA_HOME contains jdk path with version included in it . Eclipse might be using that to generate the jre path name for the said file.

I did workaround i.e. changed name of jre folder to the older version e.g.
jre1.8.0_191 is after installing update and 
jre1.8.0_60 was before update.
I renamed  jre1.8.0_191 with jre1.8.0_60 to solve the issue

Answer (score 0):

I had faced similar problem. Environment variable path problem

**JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_192**

Set the Environment variable after going

**Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\System** and select **Advanced System Settings** then set **Environment Variables**

In **System Variables** add a new variable **JAVA_HOME** and variable value = C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_192, the path of the jdk file in your system.

and **%JAVA_HOME%\bin** in the **path** of the system variables.

Hopefully the problem will solve.
After doing this It works fine for me.

Comment: @miga, Please don't do edits that invalidate flags. This answer is a 'thank you' answer, not an answer. Please check the previous answers. This one is NAA

Comment: sorry about that and thank you for the explanation. The marked answer didin't show how to set the env variable, so without the thank you this anwese provides more to the solution (others are better, also higher ranked and have more information)

Comment: @miga I think it's clear that this answer is in response to this https://stackoverflow.com/a/53398980/5468463. Maybe more concise, but still...