# Atlassian hello world JIRA build error

Tags: eclipse, jira, jira-plugin

I'm trying to work through the Atlassian hello world tutorial. I'm trying to execute the atlas-create-jira-plugin-module command in step 4-3 here: https://developer.atlassian.com/docs/getting-started/set-up-the-atlassian-plugin-sdk-and-build-a-project/put-the-final-polish-on-the-project-in-eclipse, but when I do I'm hit with this huge error. Does anyone know what the problem is? Sorry in advance for the huge wall of text.

```
atlas-create-jira-plugin-module
Executing: /Applications/Atlassian/atlassian-plugin-sdk-6.1.0/apache-maven-3.2.1/bin/mvn com.atlassian.maven.plugins:maven-jira-plugin:6.1.2:create-plugin-module -gs /Applications/Atlassian/atlassian-plugin-sdk-6.1.0/apache-maven-3.2.1/conf/settings.xml
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[WARNING]
[WARNING] Some problems were encountered while building the effective model for com.atlassian.tutorial:helloworld:atlassian-plugin:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT
[WARNING] 'build.plugins.plugin.version' for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin is missing. @ line 163, column 21
[WARNING]
[WARNING] It is highly recommended to fix these problems because they threaten the stability of your build.
[WARNING]
[WARNING] For this reason, future Maven versions might no longer support building such malformed projects.
[WARNING]
[INFO]
[INFO] Using the builder org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder with a thread count of 1
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building helloworld 1.0.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
Downloading: file:///Applications/Atlassian/atlassian-plugin-sdk-6.1.0/repository/org/apache/velocity/velocity/maven-metadata.xml
Downloading: https://maven.atlassian.com/repository/public/org/apache/velocity/velocity/maven-metadata.xml
Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/velocity/velocity/maven-metadata.xml
Downloaded: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/velocity/velocity/maven-metadata.xml (598 B at 0.9 KB/sec)
Downloaded: https://maven.atlassian.com/repository/public/org/apache/velocity/velocity/maven-metadata.xml (2 KB at 0.7 KB/sec)
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-jira-plugin:6.1.2:create-plugin-module (default-cli) @ helloworld ---
[WARNING] Error injecting: com.atlassian.maven.plugins.jira.JiraPluginModuleGenerationMojo
java.lang.TypeNotPresentException: Type com.atlassian.maven.plugins.jira.JiraPluginModuleGenerationMojo not present
    at org.eclipse.sisu.space.URLClassSpace.loadClass(URLClassSpace.java:115)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.space.NamedClass.load(NamedClass.java:46)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.space.AbstractDeferredClass.get(AbstractDeferredClass.java:48)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory.provision(ProviderInternalFactory.java:86)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.provision(InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.java:55)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory$1.call(ProviderInternalFactory.java:70)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback$Provision.provision(ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:100)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.plexus.PlexusLifecycleManager.onProvision(PlexusLifecycleManager.java:133)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback$Provision.provision(ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:109)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback.provision(ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:55)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory.circularGet(ProviderInternalFactory.java:68)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.get(InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.java:47)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$2$1.call(InjectorImpl.java:997)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:1047)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$2.get(InjectorImpl.java:993)
    at com.google.inject.Scopes$1$1.get(Scopes.java:59)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.inject.LazyBeanEntry.getValue(LazyBeanEntry.java:82)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.plexus.LazyPlexusBean.getValue(LazyPlexusBean.java:51)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.lookup(DefaultPlexusContainer.java:260)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.lookup(DefaultPlexusContainer.java:252)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultMavenPluginManager.getConfiguredMojo(DefaultMavenPluginManager.java:462)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:120)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:208)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:108)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:76)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:116)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:361)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:155)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:584)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:213)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:157)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/atlassian/maven/plugins/jira/JiraPluginModuleGenerationMojo : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:637)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:621)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:141)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:283)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(URLClassLoader.java:58)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:197)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClassFromSelf(ClassRealm.java:389)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy.loadClass(SelfFirstStrategy.java:42)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.unsynchronizedLoadClass(ClassRealm.java:259)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:242)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:227)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.space.URLClassSpace.loadClass(URLClassSpace.java:107)
    ... 41 more
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 15.006 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2015-10-26T10:47:22-05:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 16M/81M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.atlassian.maven.plugins:maven-jira-plugin:6.1.2:create-plugin-module (default-cli) on project helloworld: Execution default-cli of goal com.atlassian.maven.plugins:maven-jira-plugin:6.1.2:create-plugin-module failed: Unable to load the mojo 'create-plugin-module' in the plugin 'com.atlassian.maven.plugins:maven-jira-plugin:6.1.2' due to an API incompatibility: org.codehaus.plexus.component.repository.exception.ComponentLookupException: com/atlassian/maven/plugins/jira/JiraPluginModuleGenerationMojo : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0
[ERROR] -----------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] realm =    plugin>com.atlassian.maven.plugins:maven-jira-plugin:6.1.2
[ERROR] strategy = org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy
[ERROR] urls[0] = file:/Users/jnissenbaum/.m2/repository/com/atlassian/maven/plugins/maven-jira-plugin/6.1.2/maven-jira-plugin-6.1.2.jar
[ERROR] urls[1] = file:/Users/jnissenbaum/.m2/repository/com/atlassian/maven/archetypes/jira-plugin-archetype/6.1.2/jira-plugin-archetype-6.1.2.jar
[ERROR] urls[2] = file:/Users/jnissenbaum/.m2/repository/com/atlassian/maven/plugins/maven-amps-plugin/6.1.2/maven-amps-plugin-6.1.2.jar
[ERROR] urls[3] = file:/Users/jnissenbaum/.m2/repository/com/atlassian/core/atlassian-core/4.0/atlassian-core-4.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[4] = file:/Users/jnissenbaum/.m2/repository/com/atlassian/profiling/atlassian-profiling/1.3/atlassian-profiling-1.3.jar
[ERROR] urls[5] = file:/Users/jnissenbaum/.m2/repository/javax/servlet/servlet-api/2.3/servlet-api-2.3.jar
[ERROR] urls[6] = file:/Users/jnissenbaum/.m2/repository/p6spy/p6spy/1.3/p6spy-1.3.jar
[ERROR] urls[7] = file:/Users/jnissenbaum/.m2/repository/commons-collections/commons-collections/3.1/commons-collections-3.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[8] = file:/Users/jnissenbaum/.m2/repository/commons-lang/commons-lang/2.4/commons-lang-2.4.jar
[ERROR] urls[9] = file:/Users/jnissenbaum/.m2/repository/commons-logging/commons-logging/1.0.4/commons-logging-1.0.4.jar
[ERROR] urls[10] = file:/Users/jnissenbaum/.m2/repository/osuser/osuser/1.0-dev-log4j-1.4jdk-7Dec05/osuser-1.0-dev-log4j-1.4jdk-7Dec05.jar
[ERROR] urls[11] = file:/Users/jnissenbaum/.m2/repository/opensymphony/propertyset/1.3-21Nov03/propertyset-1.3-21Nov03.jar
[ERROR] urls[12] = file:/Users/jnissenbaum/.m2/repository/opensymphony/sitemesh/2.3/sitemesh-2.3.jar
[ERROR] urls[13] = file:/Users/jnissenbaum/.m2/repository/dom4j/dom4j/1.4/dom4j-1.4.jar
[ERROR] urls[14] = file:/Users/jnissenbaum/.m2/repository/jaxen/jaxen/1.0-FCS/jaxen-1.0-FCS.jar
[ERROR] urls[15] = file:/Users/jnissenbaum/.m2/repository/saxpath/saxpath/1.0-FCS/saxpath-1.0-FCS.jar
[ERROR] urls[16] = file:/Users/jnissenbaum/.m2/repository/msv/msv/20020414/msv-20020414.jar
[ERROR] urls[17] = file:/Users/jnissenbaum/.m2/repository/relaxngDatatype/relaxngDatatype/20020414/relaxngDatatype-20020414.jar
[ERROR] urls[18] = file:/Users/jnissenbaum/.m2/repository/isorelax/isorelax/20020414/isorelax-20020414.jar
[ERROR] urls[19] = file:/Users/jnissenbaum/.m2/repository/opensymphony/oscore/2.2.7/oscore-2.2.7.jar
[ERROR] urls[20] = file:/Users/jnissenbaum/.m2/repository/log4j/log4j/1.2.7/log4j-1.2.7.jar
[ERROR] urls[21] = file:/Users/jnissenbaum/.m2/repository/javax/mail/mail/1.4/mail-1.4.jar
[ERROR] urls[22] = file:/Users/jnissenbaum/.m2/repository/javax/activation/activation/1.1/activation-1.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[23] = file:/Users/jnissenbaum/.m2/repository/mockobjects/alt-jdk1.3/0.07/alt-jdk1.3-0.07.jar
[ERROR] urls[24] = file:/Users/jnissenbaum/.m2/repository/oscache/oscache/DEV/oscache-DEV.jar
[ERROR] urls[25] = file:/Users/jnissenbaum/.m2/repository/commons-io/commons-io/2.4/commons-io-2.4.jar
[ERROR] urls[26] = file:/Users/jnissenbaum/.m2/repository/biz/aQute/bnd/biz.aQute.bndlib/2.4.1-pr-916-atlassian-002/biz.aQute.bndlib-2.4.1-pr-916-atlassian-002.jar
[ERROR] urls[27] = file:/Users/jnissenbaum/.m2/repository/junit/junit/4.12/junit-4.12.jar
[ERROR] urls[28] = file:/Users/jnissenbaum/.m2/repository/org/hamcrest/hamcrest-core/1.3/hamcrest-core-1.3.jar
[ERROR] urls[29] = file:/Users/jnissenbaum/.m2/repository/org/apache/ant/ant/1.7.1/ant-1.7.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[30] = file:/Users/jnissenbaum/.m2/repository/org/apache/ant/ant-launcher/1.7.1/ant-launcher-1.7.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[31] = file:/Users/jnissenbaum/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/aether/aether-util/0.9.0.M2/aether-util-0.9.0.M2.jar
[ERROR] urls[32] = file:/Users/jnissenbaum/.m2/repository/javax/enterprise/cdi-api/1.0/cdi-api-1.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[33] = file:/Users/jnissenbaum/.m2/repository/javax/annotation/jsr250-api/1.0/jsr250-api-1.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[34] = file:/Users/jnissenbaum/.m2/repository/javax/inject/javax.inject/1/javax.inject-1.jar
[ERROR] urls[35] = file:/Users/jnissenbaum/.m2/repository/org/sonatype/sisu/sisu-guice/3.1.0/sisu-guice-3.1.0-no_aop.jar
[ERROR] urls[36] = file:/Users/jnissenbaum/.m2/repository/aopalliance/aopalliance/1.0/aopalliance-1.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[37] = file:/Users/jnissenbaum/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/sisu/org.eclipse.sisu.inject/0.0.0.M5/org.eclipse.sisu.inject-0.0.0.M5.jar
[ERROR] urls[38] = file:/Users/jnissenbaum/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-interpolation/1.19/plexus-interpolation-1.19.jar
[ERROR] urls[39] = file:/Users/jnissenbaum/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-component-annotations/1.5.5/plexus-component-annotations-1.5.5.jar
[ERROR] urls[40] = file:/Users/jnissenbaum/.m2/repository/org/sonatype/plexus/plexus-sec-dispatcher/1.3/plexus-sec-dispatcher-1.3.jar
[ERROR] urls[41] = file:/Users/jnissenbaum/.m2/repository/org/sonatype/plexus/plexus-cipher/1.4/plexus-cipher-1.4.jar
[ERROR] urls[42] = file:/Users/jnissenbaum/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-utils/3.0.15/plexus-utils-3.0.15.jar
[ERROR] urls[43] = file:/Users/jnissenbaum/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-archiver/1.0-alpha-9/plexus-archiver-1.0-alpha-9.jar
[ERROR] urls[44] = file:/Users/jnissenbaum/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-io/1.0-alpha-1/plexus-io-1.0-alpha-1.jar
[ERROR] urls[45] = file:/Users/jnissenbaum/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/maven-archiver/2.3/maven-archiver-2.3.jar
[ERROR] urls[46] = file:/Users/jnissenbaum/.m2/repository/org/apache/commons/commons-compress/1.4.1/commons-compress-1.4.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[47] = file:/Users/jnissenbaum/.m2/repository/org/tukaani/xz/1.0/xz-1.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[48] = file:/Users/jnissenbaum/.m2/repository/commons-validator/commons-validator/1.2.0/commons-validator-1.2.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[49] = file:/Users/jnissenbaum/.m2/repository/commons-beanutils/commons-beanutils/1.7.0/commons-beanutils-1.7.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[50] = file:/Users/jnissenbaum/.m2/repository/commons-digester/commons-digester/1.6/commons-digester-1.6.jar
[ERROR] urls[51] = file:/Users/jnissenbaum/.m2/repository/oro/oro/2.0.8/oro-2.0.8.jar
[ERROR] urls[52] = file:/Users/jnissenbaum/.m2/repository/xml-apis/xml-apis/1.0.b2/xml-apis-1.0.b2.jar
[ERROR] urls[53] = file:/Users/jnissenbaum/.m2/repository/jdom/jdom/1.0/jdom-1.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[54] = file:/Users/jnissenbaum/.m2/repository/com/atlassian/amps/plugin-module-codegen-maven-client/6.1.2/plugin-module-codegen-maven-client-6.1.2.jar
[ERROR] urls[55] = file:/Users/jnissenbaum/.m2/repository/com/atlassian/amps/plugin-module-codegen-engine/6.1.2/plugin-module-codegen-engine-6.1.2.jar
[ERROR] urls[56] = file:/Users/jnissenbaum/.m2/repository/com/atlassian/amps/plugin-module-codegen-api/6.1.2/plugin-module-codegen-api-6.1.2.jar
[ERROR] urls[57] = file:/Users/jnissenbaum/.m2/repository/org/ow2/asm/asm/5.0.3/asm-5.0.3.jar
[ERROR] urls[58] = file:/Users/jnissenbaum/.m2/repository/com/atlassian/fugue/fugue/1.0/fugue-1.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[59] = file:/Users/jnissenbaum/.m2/repository/com/googlecode/guava-osgi/guava-osgi/10.0.1/guava-osgi-10.0.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[60] = file:/Users/jnissenbaum/.m2/repository/jline/jline/0.9.94/jline-0.9.94.jar
[ERROR] urls[61] = file:/Users/jnissenbaum/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-interactivity-api/1.0-alpha-4/plexus-interactivity-api-1.0-alpha-4.jar
[ERROR] urls[62] = file:/Users/jnissenbaum/.m2/repository/plexus/plexus-utils/1.0.2/plexus-utils-1.0.2.jar
[ERROR] urls[63] = file:/Users/jnissenbaum/.m2/repository/com/atlassian/maven/archetypes/refapp-plugin-archetype/6.1.2/refapp-plugin-archetype-6.1.2.jar
[ERROR] urls[64] = file:/Users/jnissenbaum/.m2/repository/com/dmurph/JGoogleAnalyticsTracker/1.2.1-atlassian/JGoogleAnalyticsTracker-1.2.1-atlassian.jar
[ERROR] urls[65] = file:/Users/jnissenbaum/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/slf4j-nop/1.6.2/slf4j-nop-1.6.2.jar
[ERROR] urls[66] = file:/Users/jnissenbaum/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/slf4j-api/1.6.2/slf4j-api-1.6.2.jar
[ERROR] urls[67] = file:/Users/jnissenbaum/.m2/repository/com/atlassian/plugins/rest/atlassian-rest-doclet/2.9.2/atlassian-rest-doclet-2.9.2.jar
[ERROR] urls[68] = file:/Users/jnissenbaum/.m2/repository/com/atlassian/plugins/rest/atlassian-rest-common/2.9.2/atlassian-rest-common-2.9.2.jar
[ERROR] urls[69] = file:/Users/jnissenbaum/.m2/repository/com/atlassian/plugins/rest/com.atlassian.jersey-library/2.9.2/com.atlassian.jersey-library-2.9.2.pom
[ERROR] urls[70] = file:/Users/jnissenbaum/.m2/repository/com/sun/jersey/jersey-server/1.8-atlassian-13/jersey-server-1.8-atlassian-13.jar
[ERROR] urls[71] = file:/Users/jnissenbaum/.m2/repository/asm/asm/3.1/asm-3.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[72] = file:/Users/jnissenbaum/.m2/repository/com/sun/jersey/jersey-json/1.8-atlassian-13/jersey-json-1.8-atlassian-13.jar
[ERROR] urls[73] = file:/Users/jnissenbaum/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/jettison/jettison/1.1/jettison-1.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[74] = file:/Users/jnissenbaum/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/jackson/jackson-core-asl/1.9.1/jackson-core-asl-1.9.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[75] = file:/Users/jnissenbaum/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/jackson/jackson-mapper-asl/1.9.1/jackson-mapper-asl-1.9.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[76] = file:/Users/jnissenbaum/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/jackson/jackson-jaxrs/1.9.1/jackson-jaxrs-1.9.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[77] = file:/Users/jnissenbaum/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/jackson/jackson-xc/1.9.1/jackson-xc-1.9.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[78] = file:/Users/jnissenbaum/.m2/repository/commons-fileupload/commons-fileupload/1.3/commons-fileupload-1.3.jar
[ERROR] urls[79] = file:/Users/jnissenbaum/.m2/repository/com/atlassian/security/atlassian-secure-random/3.1.5/atlassian-secure-random-3.1.5.jar
[ERROR] urls[80] = file:/Users/jnissenbaum/.m2/repository/com/sun/jersey/jersey-core/1.8-atlassian-13/jersey-core-1.8-atlassian-13.jar
[ERROR] urls[81] = file:/Users/jnissenbaum/.m2/repository/javax/xml/bind/jaxb-api/2.1/jaxb-api-2.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[82] = file:/Users/jnissenbaum/.m2/repository/javax/xml/stream/stax-api/1.0-2/stax-api-1.0-2.jar
[ERROR] urls[83] = file:/Users/jnissenbaum/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/hibernate-validator/4.0.2.GA/hibernate-validator-4.0.2.GA.jar
[ERROR] urls[84] = file:/Users/jnissenbaum/.m2/repository/javax/validation/validation-api/1.0.0.GA/validation-api-1.0.0.GA.jar
[ERROR] urls[85] = file:/Users/jnissenbaum/.m2/repository/com/atlassian/jersey/atlassian-jersey-restdoc/1.0.3/atlassian-jersey-restdoc-1.0.3.jar
[ERROR] urls[86] = file:/Users/jnissenbaum/.m2/repository/com/sun/jersey/contribs/wadl-resourcedoc-doclet/1.8-atlassian-13/wadl-resourcedoc-doclet-1.8-atlassian-13.jar
[ERROR] urls[87] = file:/Users/jnissenbaum/.m2/repository/com/atlassian/annotations/atlassian-annotations/0.8.1/atlassian-annotations-0.8.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[88] = file:/Users/jnissenbaum/.m2/repository/com/atlassian/amps/standalone/6.1.2/standalone-6.1.2.pom
[ERROR] urls[89] = file:/Users/jnissenbaum/.m2/repository/com/atlassian/plugins/atlassian-plugins-osgi-testrunner/1.2.3/atlassian-plugins-osgi-testrunner-1.2.3.jar
[ERROR] urls[90] = file:/Users/jnissenbaum/.m2/repository/org/apache/wink/wink-client/1.1.3-incubating/wink-client-1.1.3-incubating.jar
[ERROR] urls[91] = file:/Users/jnissenbaum/.m2/repository/org/apache/wink/wink-common/1.1.3-incubating/wink-common-1.1.3-incubating.jar
[ERROR] urls[92] = file:/Users/jnissenbaum/.m2/repository/org/apache/geronimo/specs/geronimo-annotation_1.1_spec/1.0/geronimo-annotation_1.1_spec-1.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[93] = file:/Users/jnissenbaum/.m2/repository/com/sun/xml/bind/jaxb-impl/2.2.1.1/jaxb-impl-2.2.1.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[94] = file:/Users/jnissenbaum/.m2/repository/com/google/code/gson/gson/2.2.2-atlassian-1/gson-2.2.2-atlassian-1.jar
[ERROR] urls[95] = file:/Users/jnissenbaum/.m2/repository/com/atlassian/upm/upm-api/2.15/upm-api-2.15.jar
[ERROR] urls[96] = file:/Users/jnissenbaum/.m2/repository/javax/ws/rs/jsr311-api/1.1.1/jsr311-api-1.1.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[97] = file:/Users/jnissenbaum/.m2/repository/com/google/javascript/closure-compiler/rr2079.1/closure-compiler-rr2079.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[98] = file:/Users/jnissenbaum/.m2/repository/args4j/args4j/2.0.12/args4j-2.0.12.jar
[ERROR] urls[99] = file:/Users/jnissenbaum/.m2/repository/com/google/guava/guava/10.0.1/guava-10.0.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[100] = file:/Users/jnissenbaum/.m2/repository/com/google/protobuf/protobuf-java/2.4.1/protobuf-java-2.4.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[101] = file:/Users/jnissenbaum/.m2/repository/org/json/json/20090211/json-20090211.jar
[ERROR] urls[102] = file:/Users/jnissenbaum/.m2/repository/com/google/code/findbugs/jsr305/1.3.9/jsr305-1.3.9.jar
[ERROR] urls[103] = file:/Users/jnissenbaum/.m2/repository/com/googlecode/jarjar/jarjar/1.1/jarjar-1.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[104] = file:/Users/jnissenbaum/.m2/repository/com/yahoo/platform/yui/yuicompressor/2.4.7/yuicompressor-2.4.7.jar
[ERROR] urls[105] = file:/Users/jnissenbaum/.m2/repository/rhino/js/1.6R7/js-1.6R7.jar
[ERROR] urls[106] = file:/Users/jnissenbaum/.m2/repository/commons-codec/commons-codec/1.6/commons-codec-1.6.jar
[ERROR] urls[107] = file:/Users/jnissenbaum/.m2/repository/com/googlecode/htmlcompressor/htmlcompressor/1.4/htmlcompressor-1.4.jar
[ERROR] urls[108] = file:/Users/jnissenbaum/.m2/repository/org/apache/wink/wink-client-apache-httpclient/1.1.3-incubating/wink-client-apache-httpclient-1.1.3-incubating.jar
[ERROR] urls[109] = file:/Users/jnissenbaum/.m2/repository/org/apache/httpcomponents/httpclient/4.0.1/httpclient-4.0.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[110] = file:/Users/jnissenbaum/.m2/repository/org/apache/httpcomponents/httpcore/4.0.1/httpcore-4.0.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[111] = file:/Users/jnissenbaum/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/jcl-over-slf4j/1.6.1/jcl-over-slf4j-1.6.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[112] = file:/Users/jnissenbaum/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/archetype/archetype-common/2.2/archetype-common-2.2.jar
[ERROR] urls[113] = file:/Users/jnissenbaum/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/archetype/archetype-catalog/2.2/archetype-catalog-2.2.jar
[ERROR] urls[114] = file:/Users/jnissenbaum/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/archetype/archetype-descriptor/2.2/archetype-descriptor-2.2.jar
[ERROR] urls[115] = file:/Users/jnissenbaum/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/archetype/archetype-registry/2.2/archetype-registry-2.2.jar
[ERROR] urls[116] = file:/Users/jnissenbaum/.m2/repository/net/sourceforge/jchardet/jchardet/1.0/jchardet-1.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[117] = file:/Users/jnissenbaum/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/shared/maven-invoker/2.0.11/maven-invoker-2.0.11.jar
[ERROR] urls[118] = file:/Users/jnissenbaum/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-velocity/1.1.8/plexus-velocity-1.1.8.jar
[ERROR] urls[119] = file:/Users/jnissenbaum/.m2/repository/org/apache/velocity/velocity/1.5/velocity-1.5.jar
[ERROR] urls[120] = file:/Users/jnissenbaum/.m2/repository/org/twdata/maven/mojo-executor/1.5.2/mojo-executor-1.5.2.jar
[ERROR] Number of foreign imports: 1
[ERROR] import: Entry[import  from realm ClassRealm[project>com.atlassian.tutorial:helloworld:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT, parent: ClassRealm[maven.api, parent: null]]]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] -----------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginContainerException
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Buried in the error, I see:

```
Unsupported major.minor version 51.0
```

What JDK version do you have installed? It looks like you are trying to build with JDK 6.x, but the above message indicates that you need at least Java 7.

In particular, you will want to ensure that the `JAVA_HOME` environment variable points to Java 7 or higher.

Comment: The very latest I thought
    $ java -version
    java version "1.8.0_65"
    Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_65-b17)
    Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.65-b01, mixed mode)

Comment: Looks like I'm not the only one with this error. I'm going to try the solutions they list out. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33324363/how-to-fix-eclipse-java-virtual-machine-launcher-error#

Comment: Are you running the above command from within an IDE? Can you make sure that your `$JAVA_HOME` environment variable is also set to the right place for JDK 1.8? What if you run the atlas-create-jira-plugin-module command directly from the terminal instead?

Comment: I was running the command directly from the terminal. I checked the $JAVA_HOME variable and I set it using this command: export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home). Which I think helped because now I'm getting a much smaller error:
Failed to execute goal com.atlassian.maven.plugins:maven-jira-plugin:6.1.2:create-plugin-module (default-cli): Goal requires a project to execute but there is no POM in this directory (/Users/jnissenbaum/atlastutorial). Please verify you invoked Maven from the correct directory.

Comment: Does the `/Users/jnissenbaum/atlastutorial` directory contain a `pom.xml` file? Are you running the command from a different directory than before?

Comment: Wait, that fixed it. I was in the wrong directory, but when I went to the right one the command executed as expected. Did Oracle change something recently to cause this problem? Also thanks Scott :)

Comment: I'd guess that you have two JREs on your system, and the default search logic in the Maven scripts was pulling out the older one by accident. If you really care, you can try running the command without the JAVA_HOME setting, press ^Z to suspend before it crashes, and then `ps ax |grep maven` to look at the process list and see what version of Java is actually being invoked.

Comment: If the solution above works for you, please don't forget to accept the answer. :-)

Comment: If anyone reads this and the above doesn't work (because it stopped working after I tried the steps above). Try to follow step 1 here which worked for me: http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-set-java_home-environment-variable-on-mac-os-x/